# How to display a form in Symfony from a query to 2 entities

Tags: symfony, dql

I have the following code that works:

```
//AdminController.php
$orders_repo=$em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Orders");
$order=$orders_repo->getQuery()->getResult();
$form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

And in the OrderType form this code:

```
$builder
        ->add('customername', TextType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Numero de Causa',
                'required'=>'Requerido',
                'attr'=> array (
                    'class' => 'form-name form-control'
                )
            ));
```

The problem is when you want to display a more elaborate query to display on the form.

Something like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT u, o
                FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
                JOIN o.users u
    where o.orderid = :orderid'
 )->setParameter('orderid', $id);

 $order = $query->getResult();
 $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $order);
```

If you want to show this in the form and then update how you can do it?

Comment: Do you also want to add User data in the form?

Comment: Yes. I know with ->add('Users') but exists other way for show all information?

Comment: Not sure what's the questions here and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to display the information for that query on the form